# Silent App crash on Android 12 & 13 when using Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, sdk

I need to implement usb debugging fun in my app . I am using ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMEMT_SETTINGS intent for open developer option setting . I am able to proceed and go to the developer option but when I press the back button  my app should be their but my app crashes silently. Same process is working fine in Android 9 and on click of back I go back to the activity. I have created one sample project and everythings works fine on Android 12&13 too.

I am not able to debug the issue as nothing has been printed on logs. I can't change the gradle file as their are lots of dependencies on other modules also. Please help and give your suggestions.

I have change something on manifest files too but no luck till now.kindly support here.